# My question has 10 pictures, but I can't add them beacuse I don't have 10 reputation. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a question and I write it down and there's 10 picture in it, now after 1 hour of writing it when I wanna post it,  I got you need at least 10 reputation to post images. What should I do?

Comment: I edited it, and I'm waiting for 20 minutes to pass for posting another one with simple text, my good I changed them to links just to realize no more than 2 links is allowed either... I'm mad right now...

Comment: aask your question without the pictures.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems answered, so I'm not sure if it's important for you to add more images at this time. I'm answering this meta question for the general issue, not specifically for your question on main that I think you're referring to.

#### Some ways to avoid using lots of images.

First, as others have said, please think about whether or not you really need *ten* images. That's a lot for anything but the most complicated question. And a question that needs ten images most likely also needs a lot of text explaining those images.

In particular, if these are pictures of a terminal window, you should instead copy text from the terminal window and paste it into your question. After pasting it into your question, you can select the text in your question and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to format it properly as code. Before you format it properly, it will look something like this:

> ek@Kip:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade Ign
>   http://dl.google.com stable InRelease Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com
>   trusty InRelease Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates
>   InRelease

Formatted properly as code, it will look like this:

```
ek@Kip:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
```

#### Ways to use lots of images, if you really need to.

If you really need to show ten pictures for your question, you can include their URLs--i.e., their address--without linking them. (Because if you don't have enough reputation to post as many images as you want, you won't be able to post that many links either.) Then users with more reputation can check the pictures, and after checking them, can edit your post to include them.

*How would you include URLs without the URLs becoming links?* One way is to enclose the URLs in a code block. If the URL is on its own line, indent the line by four spaces. You can do this by adding those four spaces yourself or by selecting the line and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

The *real* purpose of code blocks is to format code-like text in a way that respects its own inbuilt spacing. However, it can also be used to prevent text from appearing as links (as you can see from my example above, where the URLs that appeared in my terminal were incidentally linkified in the wrong, non-code formatting but were not linkified in the correct, code formatting).

*How would you put an image on the Internet to link to it in the first place?* You can upload it at a site like http://postimage.org/ or https://imgur.com/.

If you want other, higher rep users to add just a couple images for you like this, that's usually reasonable. For *ten* images, this is something of a burden. Remember that whoever does you the favor of adding the images into your post *is responsible for that edit*. They must (or at least should) make sure the images are really appropriate for your post before adding them. At minimum, they must look at all the images themselves before adding them to your post.

So, if you *really* need to add ten images to your question, and you choose to use a method like this of adding the URLs and asking people to add the images for you, then **please make sure the reason so many images are needed is overwhelmingly clear from the text written in your post.**

Comment: I know this is old, but I want to add that creating and linking to an imgur.com gallery can allow someone to add basically as many pics as they want.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really have a question with 10 pictures? Are they really all needed? Start by asking a good question with a link to one or two pictures, someone will add them in later. If you get 2 upvotes for asking a good question, you will have 10 reputation. Easy as that!